# NSNotificationCenter - Observing for Notification Name with Multiple Methods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotifications, nsnotificationcenter

So, I have an object that has methods to toggle watching for a certain notification name, like so:

```
- (void)startWatchingForA
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(handleA:)
                                                 name: SomeNotificationName
                                               object: nil];
}

- (void)stopWatchingForA
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                    name: SomeNotificationName
                                                  object: nil];
}
```

Which works fine. However, I have another method, `handleB:`, that needs to respond to the same notification.

```
- (void)startWatchingForB
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(handleB:)
                                                 name: SomeNotificationName
                                               object: nil];
}

- (void)stopWatchingForB
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                    name: SomeNotificationName
                                                  object: nil];
}
```

The issue is that, should `stopWatchingA` or `stopWatchingB` be called, the object will stop watching for both. Is there some way to remove one observation instance, but not the other?

Ideally, when I call `stopWatchingForA`, I want `handleA:` to not be called, entirely independent of `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a slight redesign? Only one method to receive the notification, and two flags to indicate what you want to do with it.

```
@implementation ThisObject
{
   BOOL isWatchingForA;
   BOOL isWatchingForB;
}

- (void) registerForNotifications {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(handleNotification:)
                                             name: SomeNotificationName
                                           object: nil];
}

- (void) deregisterForNotifications {
    if( !isWatchingA && !isWatchingB ){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                name: SomeNotificationName
                                              object: nil];
    }
}


- (void) startWatchingForA {
    isWatchingForA = YES;
}
- (void) stopWatchingForA {
    isWatchingForA = NO;
}

- (void) startWatchingForB {
    isWatchingForB = YES;
}
- (void) stopWatchingForB {
    isWatchingForB = NO;
}

- (void) handleNotification: (NSNotification *)note {

    if( isWatchingForA ){
        [self handleA:note];
    }
    if( isWatchingB ){
        [self handleB:note];
    }
}

//...

@end
```

Comment: Yes, [declaring ivars in `@implementation` is legal](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF126) with a recent compiler.

Comment: And one of the more useful features too! @private implementation variables are useful in many ways.

Comment: +1 for a well thought out answer! I'll accept, but it's not the method I went with. I'll explain in my answer.

Comment: @pcperini: No need to give it the check mark if it's not the solution you used! An upvote is quite enough if you think it is helpful, thanks.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I think yours is the most appropriate solution to the question I posed. Plus, I don't want all of that rep to go to waste :)

Answer (score 1):

So blocks and [mikeash](http://mikeash.com/), once again, ended up saving my day!

One thing that I omitted in my original question was that I would like for this paradigm to be category-safe, which meant no ivars or properties as flags. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static void *AHandlerKey;
static void *BHandlerKey;

- (void)startWatchingForA
{
    // initialize `void (^aBlock)(NSNotification *)` block
    id AHandler = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName: SomeNotificationName
                                                                    object: nil
                                                                     queue: nil
                                                                usingBlock: aBlock];

    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, AHandlerKey, AHandler, OBC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

- (void)stopWatchingForA
{
    id AHandler = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, AHandlerKey);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: AHandler
                                                    name: SomeNotificationName
                                                  object: nil];
}

- (void)startWatchingForB
{
    // initialize `void (^bBlock)(NSNotification *)` block
    id BHandler = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName: SomeNotificationName
                                                                    object: nil
                                                                     queue: nil
                                                                usingBlock: bBlock];

    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, BHandlerKey, BHandler, OBC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

- (void)stopWatchingForB
{
    id BHandler = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, BHandlerKey);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: BHandler
                                                    name: SomeNotificationName
                                                  object: nil];
}
```

This way, `AHandler` receives notifications, while `aBlock` is executed, and `BHandler`/`bBlock` likewise. When I remove `AHandler` as an observer, `BHandler` is unaffected, and vice versa. Perfect!

**Update:** Big thanks to Josh Caswell who suggested the use of object association!

Comment: Very nice! I like your solution better! (I've come to favor the Block-based notification route.)

Comment: Wait, there's a problem with this: the `static` variables won't work across multiple instances of this class (assuming that a different observer object is returned each time, anyways). You could throw in a bit of associated object use.

Comment: Great idea; had no idea that was a thing! Will do, and I'll update accordingly.